# Transitioning Tailwind Dark Mode

Tags: tailwind-css

My Tailwind config has:

```
darkMode: 'selector',
```

On my `body` I have:

```
dark:bg-black dark:text-white transition-colors duration-1000
```

I have also tried adding these as defaults:

```
bg-white text-black
```

And have tried

```
transition-all
```

On my `html` tag I toggle a `dark` class on the click of a button.

Dark mode works, turning it from white to black, however, I get no transition between the colors. Note that I am able to get transition working with other things on the site so the classes are included.

How can I get the colours to transition?

Answer (score 0):

Just change `durtion-1000` to `!duration-1000`.

There **is** transition on the colors. However, the `duration-1000` is overwritten by `transition-colors` which sets the transition duration of `color` to 150ms. (They have the same specificity, so it's decided by which is declared later in the final CSS style sheets. See [Cascade order](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-6/#cascade-order).)

As per [tailwind doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property):

```
transition-colors:
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, text-decoration-color, fill, stroke;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 150ms;
```